# Activity doesn't start from broadcast receiver after home button, and start after back button

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I try to start an activity from a broadcast receiver which started from foreground service with this code

```
   val intent = Intent("my.intent")
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
   context?.startActivity(intent)
```

Activity started. But when I see activity and I press to the home button, next time when receiver tries to start the activity, the activity won't start, and if I press back button when the activity showing, next time activity will start from the receiver without any problems.

I tried to set difference flags to the start intent.
Set singleTask and singleInstance
Also, I tried to override onBackPressed() to finish activity and call finish() from onPause(). But the behavior wouldn't change. 
I start my foreground service from the main activity, and in this case, I have the same behavior. If I start my foreground service (simple by button click) and press home to minimize app in this way activity from broadcast wouldn't start too
I show toast frow receiver so I'm sure activity must start.

My Manifest

```
  <activity
      android:name=".NeededActivity"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="my.intent" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

What's the difference and how I can fix it, I need to start Activity every time when I call startActivity in the receiver. 
I've tested my code on Android 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `clearTask` flag from Intent

For more information about intent flags you can refer at the official documentation at [Activity Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent)

Also, since you are using Kotlin why not try [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko)

Use it like this

```
startActivity(intentFor<NeededActivity>().clearTask().newTask())
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't help. I start my foreground service from the main activity, and in this case, I have the same behavior. If I start my foreground service (simple by button click) and press home to minimize the app in this way activity from broadcast wouldn't start too